# Estimates for this divisor sum

Tags: number-theory, analysis, analytic-number-theory

I am reading a paper in analytic number theory. I'm stuck on a line. The author did this which I don't understand. $$\sum_{\substack{q | P \\ v(q) = \gamma}} |\mu(q)|(\frac{x}{hq} + 1) \ll \frac{x}{h}\frac{1}{\gamma!}(\sum_{p | P} \frac{1}{p})^{\gamma} $$

where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, P is a squarefree integer, $v(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, and $p$ is prime.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: The appearance of the Mobius function on the left is odd.  Since $P$ is square free, so is $q$ for every $q$ dividing $P$.  It follows that $\mu(q)=\pm 1$ , hence that $|\mu(q)|=1$ so you can simply drop that term.

Comment: @Jyerkimenon i've tried to expand the sum like so $$\frac{x}{h} \sum_{q | P} \prod_{p | q} \frac{1}{q}  + \sum_{\substack{q | P \\ v(q) = \gamma}} 1  \leq \frac{x}{h}(\sum_{p | P} \frac{1}{q})^{\gamma} + {v(P) \choose \gamma}$$. I'm not quite sure where the factor $\frac{1}{\gamma!}$ comes from.

Comment: How big is $x/h$?

Comment: Anyway, the thing you ask follows from Maclaurin inequality: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality